How to listen to ScrollBar's show and hide in full?
How to listen to ScrollBar's show and hide in full ?
scrollBar.addListener( SWT.Show, e -> ...... ) ;
scrollBar.addListener( SWT.Hide, e -> ...... ) ;

Adding SWT.Show and SWT.Hide listener to the ScrollBar only seems to listen to the visible state that method ScrollBar.setVisible(boolean) changes.
For example, the ScrollBar in a Tree can't be listened to in this way.

I doubt that there is an event since scroll bars vary so much between platforms. On macOS the bars are hardly ever visible, only showing when you are actually scrolling.
